# Using free() on struct only clearing first object

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I have a struct that is defined as a pointer. Inside, it has 2 double variables. The program keeps messing up after I try to free any of the variables of the struct type. After some print statements, I have found out that only the first object is getting freed. What can I do?

Struct definition (Can't change due to assignment)

```
struct ctype {
  double real, imag; // real & imaginary parts
};
typedef struct ctype *complex;
```

Allocating space

```
complex c;
c = malloc(sizeof(comples));
```

Current attempt at freeing space

```
free(c);
```

Current output after printing real & imag parts after freeing

```
real: 0.000000 imag: 2.001000
```

I feel like I have the project pretty well understood, but this problem seems to be breaking everything and preventing me from progressing. Any help would be appreciated. If you need more code, let me know.

Edit:
I see that I was misunderstanding what free does. After looking over things though, I am still experiencing crashes whenever I go try to reallocate memory to the pointer c. I will try to explain the project a bit more and give more code.
Basically, it is just complex numbers. When the `newComplex` function is called, it creates the pointer c and allocates space to it, and stores the values for the real and imag parts. It then returns the new complex struct.

The crashing is coming from setting the real or imag part after freeing and then reallocating space.

```
complex newComplex(double realPart, double imagPart) {
    complex c = NULL;
    c = malloc(sizeof(complex));
 ~set values & returns c~
}
complex c1 = newComplex(2.05,5.02);

~print c1 then free c1~

c1 = newComplex(7.789, 4.567);  <--- Does not execute and crashes
```

Comment: `free` does not clear memory. That's an incorrect understanding. Accessing freed memory is undefined behaviour. Just don't do it. If you want to ensure the memory is cleared to guarantee that later allocations don't see it then set the values to something (like zero) before freeing it.

Comment: The only thing you know for certain after calling free is that dereferencing the pointer you passed to it is illegal. So what's the exact thing you did? That's right, the one thing you must not do, and whose behaviour is completely undefined.

Comment: Don’t output what you freed. Never. Any such attempt is bad, it may show you ghost values, or crash your program, or worse.

Comment: Calling `free` is like checking out of a hotel room. It does not change what is in the room. If you try to access the room after checking out then that is illegal and you shouldn't do it. If you happen to get into the room then you may see things you left there or you may see something different. It depends on who uses the room after you have checked out. If you want to ensure the room is in a certain state then you should do that before checking out. Or just check out if you don't care whether the next person sees what you have left behind.

Comment: What you *should* probably do is to clear the pointer itself. I.e. after calling `free(c)` do `c = NULL`. This way, subtle mysterious bugs will become obvious and (usually) easily fixable. (dereferncing NULL pointer is equally invalid to dereferencing freed pointer, but the former manifests itself immediately)

Comment: @kaylum To my knowledge, in programming it is customary to clean the memory right after allocating it, not just before freeing. The latter is only used for passwords etc. but that’s another story.

Comment: Important side note:  I do not think that it is correct to allocate using `sizeof(complex)`.  This would allocate memory equal to the size of the pointer itself (an address) rather than the memory being pointed to.  I believe it should be `sizeof(*complex)`.  This will make sure the allocated memory will be the same as the size of the data being pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

`free` generally does not clear memory. That is not part of the specification of what it does. `free` merely updates a database to say the memory is no longer reserved.

`free` might alter the memory that has been freed, either because it uses that memory as part of the database, to help track what memory is available, or because debugging features have been turned on, so freed memory is deliberately “scribbled” over so that incorrect attempts to use it as if it still had valid data in it are likely to fail and reveal program bugs. You cannot rely on either of these behaviors without specific documentation for the implementation of the memory allocation routines.

Additionally, the compiler may know what `free` does. It is part of the C standard. Because of this, a compiler may treat a pointer to memory that has been freed as an invalid pointer, and attempting to use the pointer might not actually access the memory it used to point to. Using such a pointer does not have behavior defined by the C standard, so the compiler does not have to treat it as a normal variable with a value, and optimization during compilation may produce unexpected effects.

Comment: Ok that all made sense to me but my program is still crashing. I added some more code to the post. would that be the correct implementation? It is still crashing when I try to create a new complex number

Comment: `c = malloc(sizeof(complex))` is wrong. `malloc` must be passed the size of the memory you want to allocate, but `sizeof(complex)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the thing it points to. Use `c = malloc(sizeof *c)`. In the future, do not ask second questions in the comments or by editing the question. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. Your initial question was answered, and that should complete it. If you have other questions, enter them separately. But keep in mind Stack Overflow is intended to provide knowledge, not a debugging service.